# F# - This code isn't compiling for me

Tags: f#

This code isn't compiling for me:  `let countDown = [5L .. −1L .. 0L];;`

I have a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596153656) (page 33) that says it should return this:
`val countDown : int list = [5L; 4L; 3L; 2L; 1L; 0L]`

Compiler Error:

```
Program.fs(42,24): error FS0010: Unexpected character '−' in expression
>
> let countDown = [5L .. −1L .. 0L];;

  let countDown = [5L .. −1L .. 0L];;
  -----------------------^
```

The book's wrong. but why? is it an update to the language? what is the way to achieve that?

**Edit:** the problem was that the `−` character copied from the PDF, isn't the `-` character.

Comment: I'm sure the compiler probably gave you an error other than "me no compile".  You should share it.

Comment: yes, and what is your question ?

Comment: Well this book is also mistaken about the `int` instead `int64`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your original code works fine for me even without the modifications that Igor suggested:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

> let l = [ 10L .. -1L .. 0L ];;
val l : int64 list = [10L; 9L; 8L; 7L; 6L; 5L; 4L; 3L; 2L; 1L; 0L]
```

A possible subtle error is that if you (for example) pasted the code from Word (or some other program), it may have replaced the `-` symbol with some other type of dash that looks the same, but has actually a different code.

Another way to break the code is to remove some spaces - for example, there must be a space between `..` and `-1L`. Otherwise, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You're right. The `−` that I copied from the ebook, isn't the `-` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let countDown = [5L .. (-1L) .. 0L];;
```

Or this:

```
let countDown = [5 .. -1 .. 0];;
```

Both of the above will work.

Here is some output:

```
> let countDown = [5 .. -1 .. 0];;

val countDown : int list = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0]

> let countDown = [5L .. (-1L) .. 0L];;

val countDown : int64 list = [5L; 4L; 3L; 2L; 1L; 0L]
```

Comment: Now it's working. I don't sure why it didn't before, I'm using vs2010 too.